# Find conditional expectation given symmetric r.v

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation

How to find $E[\sin(X)|\cos(X)]$, if X - a symmetric random variable?

My attempt: I tried to prove that $\sin(X)$ is $\sigma(\cos(X))$-measurable. Then it can be argued that $E[\sin(X)|\cos(X)]=\sin(X)$. But in this case, symmetry is not used.

I am completely sure that this is the wrong answer.

Comment: Can you show that $\mathbb E[\sin(X)f(\cos(X))]=0$ for any measurable bounded $f$?

Comment: @nejimban: yes, because $\sin(x)$ - odd function. But how it can help to me?

Comment: Well $\mathbb E[\sin(X)f(\cos(X))]=0$ for all bounded measurable $f$ *means* that $\mathbb E[\sin(X)\mid\cos(X)]=0$ by definition of the conditional expectation.

Comment: @nejimban: i just have this definition of conditional expectation with respect to a random variable: ${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} [X|Y]:=\operatorname {E} [X|\sigma (Y)]}$. Are these formulations equivalent?

Comment: Yes, these are the same.

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry $$E(\sin (X) |\cos (X))$$ $$=E(\sin (-X) |\cos (-X))=E(-\sin (X) |\cos (X))$$ $$=-E(\sin (X) |\cos (X))$$ so $E(\sin (X) |\cos (X))=0.$

Comment: Will be such remark correct: $$E(\sin (X) |\cos (X))$$ $$=E(\sin (-X) |\cos (X))=E(-\sin (X) |\cos (X))$$ $$=-E(\sin (X) |\cos (X))$$ so $E(\sin (X) |\cos (X))=0.$ ? I just corrected first equality and I don't see any contradictions

Comment: The first equality is not justified. If you want to use symmetry of $X$ you should, change $X$ to $-X$ at both places and use the fact that $\cos (-X)=\cos (X)$. That is what I did in my answer. @Сalendula